# symfony user secured area check

Tags: php, security, symfony

I have a secured area for logged users
like this-->

```
firewalls:
    members_secured_area:
                pattern: ^/
                provider: entity_searchers
                anonymous: ~
                form_login:
                    check_path: /searchers/login_check
                    login_path: /searchers/login
                    default_target_path: /searchers/
                logout:
                    path:   /searchers/logout
                    target: /searchers/login

    crm_secured_area:
                pattern: ^/crm/
                provider: entity_crmusers
                anonymous: ~
                form_login:
                    check_path: /crm/login_check
                    login_path: /crm/login
                    default_target_path: /crm/customers
                logout:
                    path:   /crm/logout
                    target: /crm/login
                remember_me:
                    #token_provider: entity_crmusers
                    key: someS3cretKey
                    name: NameOfTheCookie
                    lifetime: 3600 # in seconds
                    secure: false
                    httponly: true
                    always_remember_me: false
                    remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
access_control:
    members_login:
        path: /searchers/login
        roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
    members_register:
        path: /searchers/register
        roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
    members_area:
        path: /searchers/.*
        roles: ROLE_USER

    crm_login:
        path: /crm/login
        roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
    crm_register:
        path: /crm/register
        roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
    crm_area:
        path: /crm/.*
        roles: ROLE_CRM
```

so when the user is in the secured area I can see he is logged,
but when he is getting back to main page or to mysite.com/about page
I cant know he is logged or not...

is there a way to know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller you can get the user with $this->getUser(). When the user is logged it returns an instance of the User class, otherwise it returns NULL, so you can do something like:

```
$user = $this->getUser();

$is_logged = isset($user);
```

$is_logged is boolean and is true if the user is logged and false otherwise.

Comment: yes I know this, but this is valid only inside the secured area... it doesn't work on the main page for example.

Answer (score 0):

You get a valid user only under the secured area (estimated trough `pattern`). Therefore everything not matching the given `pattern` is not under the firewall and has no user token. You can change this by securing the whole site and with a new access rule

```
firewalls:
    crm_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/crm/
        # ... stuff
    members_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        # ... all other config

access_control:
    # ... all your existing access rules
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

The last rule allows all routes, which doesn't matched any rule yet to access them anonymously and you have access to the user token (if one authenticated) in all controllers.

Comment: I edited my post so you could see the full picture, as you see I have 2 types of users and 2 firewalls, in your offer, one firewall disturbs the other.

Comment: Two types of firewall are not the problem, as you can share the security context, but with two different user providers... I think you can't translate between the different users. But your use case is a little bit different. Try to put the `members_secured_area` after the `crm_secured_area`. So only searches are also authenticated on the mainpage, but crm users only in crm. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

found this solution, simply place in the pattern of the main site : ^/(?!crm)
means not to include the folder crm.

firewalls:
    members_secured_area:
                pattern: ^/(?!crm)
                provider: entity_searchers
                anonymous: ~
                form_login:
                    check_path: /searchers/login_check
                    login_path: /searchers/login
                    default_target_path: /searchers/
                logout:
                    path:   /searchers/logout
                    target: /searchers/login

```
crm_secured_area:
            pattern: ^/crm/
            provider: entity_crmusers
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /crm/login_check
                login_path: /crm/login
                default_target_path: /crm/customers
            logout:
                path:   /crm/logout
                target: /crm/login
            remember_me:
                #token_provider: entity_crmusers
                key: someS3cretKey
                name: NameOfTheCookie
                lifetime: 3600 # in seconds
                secure: false
                httponly: true
                always_remember_me: false
                remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
```